# Plot single bar or rectangle with colors based on group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a single bar or rectangle plot in R with colors based on some groupings and order based on some values. See example below:

[image]

For those interested in more detail, this is what I am trying to replicate: http://www.broadinstitute.org/cmap/help_topics_linkified.jsp (lots of examples of this plot at the bottom of the page)

**EDIT** (based on comments): The y-axis values are ranks that change with the score column. The colors represent a grouping with positive score values in green, negative in red, and black lines for a set of "selected" rows. This is **not** a stacked bar plot. The values on the y-axis (be it rank or score) are not cumulative and the group region for the "selected" (black) group can be distributed across the other three group regions (as shown in example data below).

Example:

```
structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("positive", "negative", "null", 
"selected"), class = "factor"), rank = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7.5, 
7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 10, 11, 12, 13), xaxis = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), score = c(0.85, 0.7, 0.55, 0.4, 0.25, 0, 0, 
0, 0, -0.5, -0.65, -0.8, -0.95)), .Names = c("group", "rank", 
"xaxis", "score"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")

      group rank xaxis score
1  positive  1.0     1  0.85
2  positive  2.0     1  0.70
3  selected  3.0     1  0.55
4  positive  4.0     1  0.40
5  positive  5.0     1  0.25
6      null  7.5     1  0.00
7      null  7.5     1  0.00
8  selected  7.5     1  0.00
9      null  7.5     1  0.00
10 negative 10.0     1 -0.50
11 selected 11.0     1 -0.65
12 negative 12.0     1 -0.80
13 negative 13.0     1 -0.95
```

I tried the following but I am looking for a bar or rectangle, not points.

```
ggplot(df, aes(xaxis,rank,colour=group)) + 
    geom_point(size=3) + 
    scale_colour_manual(values=c("positive"="green", "negative"="red", "null"="grey", "selected"="black")) + 
    theme_bw() + scale_y_reverse() + scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL)
```

[image]

stacked `geom_bar()` and `geom_rect()` don't seem to work with continuous `y` values.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE** (using @bjoseph's solution to replicate the exact plot shown in the link above)

```
df$size = as.factor(1)
df$height = 1
ggplot(df, aes(1,x=size,y=height,fill=group,group=rank)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity') + science_theme +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("positive"="green", "negative"="red", "null"="grey", "selected"="black")) + theme_bw() +
    scale_y_reverse(breaks=NULL) + scale_x_discrete(breaks=NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear as to whether you want 4 regions (one for each unique value of A, B, C, D) or one region for each row.

Comment: use `fill=group` instead of `colour=group` and `geom_bar(stat="identity")` instead of `geom_point()`

Comment: @joran I want essentially rows with colors based on their rank/value. So the regions are not prespecified but change according to data.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question, but @scoa has the basic idea for you either way.

Comment: @scoa - geom_bar(stat="identity") gives cumulative values, I think. I want to represent actual y-values not distinct regions for the 4 groups. I will clarify the question

Comment: I've read your edit several times, and I'm sorry, but I have no idea what your desired output is. Perhaps someone else can decipher this.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity. I have tried to clean up the explanation and data. Hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
df = structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
                                        4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
                    value = 1:13), .Names = c("group", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                               -13L), class = "data.frame")

df$size=as.factor(1)
df$height=1
ggplot(df, aes(1,x=size,y=height,fill=group,group=value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',color="black") + 
  theme_bw()
```

It produces the attached plot.

[image]

The `color="black"` command inside `geom_bar` produces black outlines around your groups. You can also suppress or manually label the y-axis if you need/want.

Comment: Thanks @bjoseph this comes close but the y-axis seems to be cumulative which makes the lower ranks (group 'B' in green) look a lot bigger that the higher ranks (group 'A' in red)

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, the `group=value` was the key in getting the bars to come out as per the value. Using the height is very useful to me as well, as I can make the "selected" rows slightly larger for better viewing. Amazing solution! Thanks.